# C# catch not working (invalid token)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013

```
        public Boolean Delete(Int32 HolidayNo)
    {
        //provides the functionality for the delete class

        //create an instance of the data connection class called MyDatabase
        clsDataConnection MyDatabase = new clsDataConnection();
        //add the HolidayNo parameter passed to this function to the list of parameters to use in the database
        MyDatabase.AddParameter("@HolidayNo", HolidayNo);
        //execute the stored procedure in the database
        MyDatabase.Execute("sproc_tblHolidays_Delete");
        //return value for function
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The catch is saying invalid token. No idea how to fix...

For those curious, I'm making a delete function to delete certain values in my database for University.

Comment: Where's the `try`?

Comment: Start from here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this a compiler or runtime error? Sounds and looks like compiler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an `Unexpected Token` error is that your `catch` block is completely outside of your method. Also, you're missing the `try` portion of the `try / catch`. To correct this, put the `catch` block inside your method and put the rest of your code in a `try` block just before the `catch`:

```
public Boolean Delete(Int32 HolidayNo)
{
    try
    {
        clsDataConnection MyDatabase = new clsDataConnection();
        MyDatabase.AddParameter("@HolidayNo", HolidayNo);
        MyDatabase.Execute("sproc_tblHolidays_Delete");
        return true;
    }    
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, worked a treat! Thank you Rufus L.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to add a try and then check the exception details for any inner exceptions.

```
public Boolean Delete(Int32 HolidayNo)
{
    try
    {
        //provides the functionality for the delete class

        //create an instance of the data connection class called MyDatabase
        clsDataConnection MyDatabase = new clsDataConnection();
        //add the HolidayNo parameter passed to this function to the list of parameters to use in the database
        MyDatabase.AddParameter("@HolidayNo", HolidayNo);
        //execute the stored procedure in the database
        MyDatabase.Execute("sproc_tblHolidays_Delete");
        //return value for function
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know how that compiled.  Please begin by cleaning up your method.  Like so:

```
public Boolean Delete(Int32 HolidayNo)
{
    var deleted = false;
    try {
        if (HolidayNo > 0) {
            //provides the functionality for the delete class

            //create an instance of the data connection class called MyDatabase
            clsDataConnection MyDatabase = new clsDataConnection();
            //add the HolidayNo parameter passed to this function to the list of parameters to use in the database
            MyDatabase.AddParameter("@HolidayNo", HolidayNo);
            //execute the stored procedure in the database
            MyDatabase.Execute("sproc_tblHolidays_Delete");

            deleted = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Log exception ex
        return deleted;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't put return inside finally.

Comment: Also, this sample completely changes the original behavior of swallowing the exception, and adds new validation on the input that was not specified in the original method...

Comment: Sorry.  Yep.  Trying to type without intellisense.  I've updated it.

Comment: I added validation for the input.  I never call a database directly without validating the input... waste of resources.

Comment: I don't understand that variable answer.. I need to explain my code to my tutor and I won't be able to with this one

Comment: Your current method is returning a boolean for whether or not the method executed without an error.  What it should be doing is confirming the item has been deleted and returning the result.  I added a variable for "deleted" to your method.  In a perfect world, your SPROC would return a boolean if the delete succeeded.

Comment: Also, since you are catching the exception and not letting it bubble up, your application will have no knowledge of an error.  It is best practice to log the error.